# Last week, this week formula for list view

Tags: force.com

I need to create a list view to show cases of this week and last week in salesforce. Can anybody help me attain it?
thank you in advance

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I need to create formula to attain this as it can not be attained through standard functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the correct filter in your list view, no need to create a formula field for this.

[image: Created after last week]

Comment: Hey thanks Robin De Bondt, the above formula worked. Can you pls help futher for Current week too

Comment: Just play with the filter [using relative date values](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en_US).